# How to install visual studio tools for office?

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2010, vsto

How to install visual studio tools for office runtime in order that I can use Word 2010 Document template in Visual Basic 2010?

Answer (score 1):

in Solution Explorer , Right Click on References >> Add References >>Microsoft.Office.Interop 
use in your form :

```
  Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

or find on google Interop.MSDACS.dll an copy to assembly folder,
and Excel example : http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel-vbnet

and for Word ex: [clic link here for Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383)

Answer (score 1):

> How to install visual studio tools for office runtime in order that I can use Word 2010 Document template in Visual Basic 2010?

See [Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44074).

VSTO is a part of Visual Studio. It is included in paid editions only. The Express editions are not supported (except the Community edition of Visual Studio 2013).

Typically you need to include the VSTO runtime as a prerequsite to the add-in installer. See [Publishing an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767(v=vs.100).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio 2015 Community, go to [Office Developer Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx) 
and click "Get Office Developer Tools", which takes you to:
http://aka.ms/getlatestofficedevtools

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx